# Running MSI uninstaller with elevated privilege

Tags: c#, windows-installer, admin, uninstallation

I have created a Window Setup Project, and added a few custom installer classes to the main apps, so to include it in the Custom Action section of the Setup Project. Im not using any third party installer program just plain Visual Studio Setup project.

I have a custom installer class for my app and in the Uninstall function I have included a function to kill the process, and remove the extra files created in the program directory.
It work in windows XP but not in 7. So I'm assuming it has to do with UAC. How can I force run an uninstaller with admin privilege?

here my my code for the Uninstaller override:

```
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.Uninstall(savedState);
    try
    {
       KillProcess();
       DeleteAppPathFolder();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}

private void KillProcess()
{
    for (; ; )
    {
        Process[] procMain = Process.GetProcessesByName("TaskbarNotificator");
        if (procMain.Length > 0)
        {
            procMain[0].Kill();
        }
        else
            break; 
    }
}

private void DeleteAppPathFolder()
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo
        (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    string sProgram = Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, GLOBALS.APP_DIR_NAME);

    if (Directory.Exists(sProgram))
        Directory.Delete(sProgram, true);
}
```

Comment: It is unclear whether you are producing an MSI or if you have a custom application that uninstalls your product.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by producing MSI. I have created an Installer Class to my main application which then is added to the MSI installer project as part of the Custom Actions. The code I've pasted is part of the Uninstall override function.

Answer (score 2):

To make a custom action run with full privileges you can make sure that it's scheduled as deferred with no impersonation. Basically, it must use the [msidbCustomActionTypeInScript and msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flags inside the MSI.

This is done differently for each setup authoring tool. If you cannot find a way to set it, please give us more details about what you are using to create your MSI.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm reading the link, but there is no indication where I have to type the flags. Is it in the CustomActionData field?

Comment: What are you using to create your package? Visual Studio setup project, WiX etc.?

Comment: Visual Studio Setup Project. There is something I have to clarify though. I want to Run the Uninstall-er in admin mode since there is a custom code in the installer class which overrides the uninstaller class. I don't know if the solution you proposed is the correct one.

Comment: This is the correct approach for running custom actions as an Administrator. Which Visual Studio version are you using? In VS 2010 the custom action should be deferred with no impersonation by default. Also, did you try debugging your code to see what exactly fails?

Comment: I thought the solution you provided was not relevant to what I wanted, so I moved my question to this post                                                                       [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933477/visual-studio-setup-project-how-can-i-force-an-uninstaller-to-run-in-administra)