# Visual Studio Setup Project: How Can I force an Uninstaller to run in Administrator mode?

Tags: c#, uac, uninstallation, administrator

I've created a Visual studio Setup Project, and I have an Installer Classes created for my main App. In this Installer Class, I overridden the Uninstaller function to clean extra folders created by my app. This works fine in windows XP, but not in Windows 7 since I assume it has something to do with UAC. How Can I force my Uninstaller to elevate privileges?

I've asked this question in another post, but I wasn't clear on my intentions.

I've found these links but I don't know if it's relevant: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370852.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370134%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

---

### UPDATE (11/7/2011)

I found out about **Orca** which it can be used to modify the msi install app properties, but there are no proper documentation for it, (or examples/tutorials). So here are the steps I took to fix this issue:

1. open the appInstal.msi with Orca.
2. from the Left Tables click on customAction
3. add a new entry to the end of all the rows (by double clicking a new row)
4. type Elevate_Install_Uninstall for Action names and 3072 for type
5. type ALL for target and leave Source empty

Hope this helps someone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that you created a new custom action which executed when uninstalling your MSI package. To run a custom action elevated — either on install or on uninstall — it has to be *deferred* and it has to be marked with *noimpersonation* flag.

In WiX, you would set these properties of the [`CustomAction` element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_customaction.htm):

- `Execute="deferred"` and
- `Impersonate="no"`.

In terms of Windows Installer, your custom action has to have these bits set: `msidbCustomActionTypeInScript` + `msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate`; see [Custom Action In-Script Execution Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368069.aspx).

Comment: How Do I set these bits? I don't see any window in the VS2010 IDE.

Comment: @ArmenB. Sorry but I don't know how to do it in VS2010 IDE. There might not be such option at all. These bits go to `Type` column of [`CustomAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368062.aspx) table in the MSI database. You can edit your MSI with Orca and test it. (Note: in Orca you would use *numerical* values.)

Comment: Thank you Alexy. I'll do some more research on Orca, and post the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Vista's UAC is similar to window's 7's so you should find some help here:

http://www.professionalvisualstudio.com/blog/2007/10/05/enabling-your-application-for-uac-on-vista/

This write up details how to adjust your app to run without running into problems with UAC.

It allows you to add a manifest file to your solution to make sure it runs at a certain level privilege wise.

Comment: This doesn't describe how to elevate the UNINSTALLER. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 1):

Add these attributes to the Uninstall procedure:

```
    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
    }
```